# Creating physical folders and FTP account with bindings in Apache2

Tags: apache2, ftp, webserver, vsftpd

Our client wants 2 subdomains creating:

**mobile.website.co.uk**

**5thbirthday.website.co.uk**

I did this on the DNS server pointing them to the IP where the website was hosted.

I then SSH into the Linux Ubuntu 12.04 box and navigate using: 
`cd /var/www/` and used `sudo mkdir mobile` and the same for 5thbirthday.

I need to create a binding in apache2 server but how can i do this?

In the GUI version of Linux I edited the 'sites enabled' file and added the physical location, default document and server IP. But how do i edit a file in SSH?

I tried the command (within the mobile folder to practice) `touch test.txt` and then `edit test.txt` I am able to edit the file but how do i save it?

I then need to give a user FTP access to the /var/www folder, currently they only have permissions to a random folder called, 'our-website' which contains nothing and is obviously redundant.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

SSH access should give you remote access to a machine *somewhere*, which then allows you bash access. If you want to edit a "test" text file, try:

```
vim test.txt
```

`i` or `insert`

```
"foobar, or what you want here"

ctrl-c > shift > wq
```

that should work, let me know of the results. As for the FTP, you just include the user credentials in the login, as for SSH, like so:

`user` = user

`domain.com` = domain

normally, to visit the site you would enter www.domain.com to visit it. However, to SSH properly you must include the user. This *may* be your problem. Try this:

`user@domain.com`

instead of `ssh domain.com` and then logging in that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my question was more how to create host headers in apache2. but if you could re-write your answer to include, 1) creating a folder (var\www\mobile) 2) creating a test htm file within that folder 3) creating the binding for mobile.website.com for the folder then creating FTP access for the mobile folder with read write delete apend permissions i will award you with the bounty.